# Multi-conditional query in Cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, conditional-statements, cakephp-3.0

I am looking for a solution for multi-conditional query in Cakephp 3 using MySql.
Here is my Items table:

```
ID|Name|Status|PID
---------------------
1 | A  |   A  |1,6,9
---------------------
2 | B  |   D  |2,5
---------------------
3 | C  |   A  |3,7,0
---------------------
4 | D  |   A  |3,7
---------------------

$numbers[]={6,0};
```

The following query works well and return all items in A status.

```
$items = $this->Items->find('all',['conditions' => ['Status' => 'A']]);
```

However, I would like to get all items with A status **When** PID includes **$numbers**, which are ID 1 and 3

**Update:**
I found this works for 3, but I need it for an array of numbers:

```
$items = $this->Items->find('all',['conditions' => ['Status' => 'A','FIND_IN_SET(\'3\',PID)']]);
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: When asking such SQL/DBMS related questions it's advised to mention the DBMS that you're using. Also please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`). Can one assume that you are using MySQL, and that you want to know how to utilize `FIND_IN_SET()`? Or maybe it's Postgres and you're looking for `string_to_array()`?

Comment: @ndm Thanks for your comment. I mentioned cake version in title and tag, and now I added it to the question. DBMS is MySQL

Comment: I saw that, but that's only the major version, the _exact_ version number has a format of `major.minor.patch`. There can be quite some differences between minor versions, and even patch versions, hence it's adivsed to post the exact version number.